# Map - finding nearest value?

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I am trying find nearest RGB value in `QMap` (I know it probably should be HSV, but that is not the problem). Here is what I got so far:

```
        it = images_map.find(current_rgb);

        if(it != images_map.begin()){
            mi = images_map.lowerBound(current_rgb).value();
        }
        else{
            mi = images_map.upperBound(current_rgb).value();
        }
```

My map looks like this has that indexes:

```
images_map[ 4283914078 ] 
images_map[ 4284046165 ] 
images_map[ 4284902241 ] 
images_map[ 4289239953 ] 
images_map[ 4282200377 ] 
images_map[ 4289440688 ]
```

When my `current_rgb` is for example `4285046165` it is OK, but if there is some value greater than greatest index, program crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a custom comparison in your map?

Comment: nope, anyway it is `QMap` from QT lib.

Comment: Ok, removed STL tag (QMap is from Qt lib, not STL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly because `.value()` tries to de-reference a non-existing item?

This looks like your own custom map implementation (or wrapper), but your logic appears to be incorrect

1. You call `lowerBound` every time - except if the item you are looking for is the first in the map
2. If it is the first in the map, you do a search again???
3. If it's not you search again (which if already found is repeating the operation again), else if not found, looks for nearest (which is okay), however do you handle the case where there is none (i.e. in `lowerBound`)?

The logic should be something like:

```
it = images_map.find(current_rgb);

if(it == images_map.end())
{
  it = images_map.lowerBound(current_rgb);
  if (it == images_map.begin())
  {
    it = images_map.upperBound(current_rgb);
    if (it == images_map.end()) 
      // throw error
  }
  // now you know you have a valid iterator - de-reference
  mi = *it.value();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is better now, but in what condition error could occured?

Comment: most likely because of the following, `find()` returns `end()`, in and therefore you end up doing an `upperBound()` - which also returns `end()` - which is de-referenced (`.value()`), causing the problem.

Comment: but I asked about your code, you do onlny `lowerBound` so maybe we should check for `begin()`?

Comment: yeah - I didn't fully write it out... I think you get the idea? If not I can fix the example...

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
images_map.upperBound(current_rgb)
```

May return

```
images_map.end()
```

In that case you should not call `value()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the iterator out of range problem by adding sentinel values `0x000000` and `0xFFFFFF` (once). That way, you always have a valid lower- and upperbound. Of course, this may affect the outcome of your algorithm. E.g. if your "smallest" real color was pure blue (`0x0000FF`), then dark blue (`0x00007F`) will now find black, not pure blue. This is easily fixed by two comparisons, of course.

With the sentinels in place, call `QMap::lower_bound`. You need to check whether you've actually found a precise match: if `*lower_bound` is the value you want, return it. Else, `lower_bound` points to the first element that's bigger than your input. Therefore, `--lowerbound` points to the last element that's smaller than your input. Check which of the two is closer.

Note that the only way `lower_bound` can point to `begin` is when your input is precisely `0x000000` (the sentinel), in which case you won't get to `--lower_bound`. No range error there. By the same logic, the end sentinel `0xFFFFFF` means you'll always find an `lower_bound`.